# PolicyMaker for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I still have a Windows Server 2003 domain. We'll be moving this to Server 2008 R2 in February. I know in 2006, Microsoft bought DesktopStandard and moved their PolicyMaker product into what's now known as the Group Policy Preferences. Is there anyway to still get PolicyMaker for Server 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if you can install the actual PolicyMaker product, or do you just want the functionality?

If you just want the functionality, its worth noting that you don't actually have to upgrade your DCs to Server 2008/R2 in order to use Group Policy Preference extensions.

To add preference items to your GPOs, you must edit the GPO from a computer running Vista/2008 or higher.

To have the client computers understand and process preference items, you need to install the Group Policy Preference client-side extensions (CSEs) on your XP/2003 computers. This is easiest via WSUS, or even a computer startup script if you don't have WSUS in place.

Comment: So can this be managed by the server Group Policy? I'm looking to modify it once and have it propogate to all client machines with the CSEs installed.

Comment: You cannot edit preference items from a 2003 server. You need to use Group Policy Management on Windows Server 2008, Vista or 7 to do the actual editing, but the point is that your DCs don't have to be running 2008 to take advantage of the functionality.

Comment: See KB943729 for additional info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943729