# Why are network printers not available in the Add Printer Wizard...when run over a network?

Tags: windows-xp, network-printer

From a Windows 2003 server machine I browsed the network to an XP client (\computername in Explorer) then double-clicked Printers and Faxes and then Add Printer.  In the wizard, normally the second screen asks if you want to install a local printer or a network printer.  Well, in this case, it seems to assume I want a local printer, because the second screen is what would normally be the third screen if you chose local printer and clicked Next.

I want to install a network printer on a remote machine for its local users.  Is this not possible?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections made to a network printer exist only in the relevant user's session.

What you are attempting to do is install a printer for all users of the remote machine, and such a printer can only be locally attached, i.e. USB or parallel. You cannot connect to a shared printer in this case. It can also be a TCP/IP printer port which you create on the remote machine, but in this case you are bypassing the shared printer and printing directly to the printer.

Comment: Ah, okay.  For some reason I thought you could install a shared printer for all users.  I guess that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kev: You can script it with a login script if you are using active directory. So all users will have that printer added when they login.

Comment: You could script it, but nowadays the preferred method is to use Group Policy preferences, its just sooo much nicer.

Comment: @Graeme: good idea, but alas, we are pre-R2.

Comment: @Kev: you can still use preferences, see my previous answer on the topic here: http://serverfault.com/questions/84056/policymaker-for-windows-server-2003/84072#84072

Comment: Sadly, we only have XP and older clients.

Comment: :-O
Words cannot express the amount of sympathy I have for you.... have a cookie ;-)